# How to set value of 'state' (status) field of sale.order using c# code in Odoo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, odoo, odoo-11

I'm inserting sales order by c# successfully, but this order going to Quotation by default.

Now, if i'm success full passed value of 'state'(status) fields of sale.order then this entry goes to Order instead of  Quotation.

But i don't know how to set 'state' of sale.order using c# code ?

Please have look,

```
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("partner_id", liCustomerID);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("user_id", liEmployee_ID);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("name", loSales.lsTransReference);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("date_order", loSales.lsTransactionDate);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("state", "done");
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("note", loSales.lsComment);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("validity_date", loSales.lsCompletedDate);
loRecordPairSalesOrder.Add("amount_total", 
Convert.ToString(loSales.lfMainAmount));
liOrder_ID = loRpcRecord.create(Common.lsDbName, liUserid, 
Common.lsDbPassword, "sale.order", "create", loRecordPairSalesOrder);
```

Comment: Instead of setting the `state` of `sale.order`s "manually", you should call `action_confirm()` by using the web api. That's because Odoo will do a lot of stuff on confirmation, for example creating projects or pickings, but only when used with this method.

Comment: @CZoellner please let me know how to pass in my syntax,thanks

Comment: First it would be nice by you substituting your "Code Image" with actual code ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner I edited my answer as code please have a look, we just focus on 'state'- for sale.order

Comment: `loRpcRecord.create(Common.lsDbName, liUserid, Common.lsDbPassword, "sale.order", "action_confirm", method_params);` -> method_params should be a list of parameters, for this method a list of order IDs should be enough; In python xmlrpc the call would look like `common.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, "sale.order",  "action_confirm", [[order_ids_to_confirm]])`